# airflow: 1.7: DAG not being updated in GUI

Tags: airflow

I have my dag file `test1.py` defined under `/opt/airflow/dags` directory. Initially, the file has only one task, `test1_task01`. In my GUI, the dag shows up correctly with only one task. However, when I add another task to my DAG that looks like:

```
DAG - test1_task01 <- test2_task01 (representative - not airflow syntax)
```

I do not see the updated DAG in my GUI. The GUI still has the old DAG. `airflow list_tasks <dagname>` shows the correct DAG relationships and `airflow scheduler` executes the latest version, but the GUI somehow is not pulling the latest info.

How do I get an updated view of my DAGs via the GUI?

Comment: i always just restart everything (webserver/scheduler) until it starts working.

Comment: Not exactly the same thing (new dag vs updating existing dag) but consider taking a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43606311/refreshing-dags-without-web-server-restart-apache-airflow, it helped me.

Comment: I had the same problem, but after 3 or 5 minutes the dag appeared. It may be a matter of the webserver update time.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this problem in a code tab, it would not update. Turns out it is not updated due to the mistake in the DAG script. Airflow loads most recent valid version and the error is logged on the `/home` page. Look it up there, fix the problem in the script and code should update just fine.

Comment: Also update can have a decent timeout. Just to be sure hit reload a couple of times if page is not updated on the first load

Answer (score 1):

Its also possible that , If you creating new DAG , you might have used the same dag_id  from the previous DAGs which is successfully running . In that case airflow GUI doesn't show any error or Hint why its not being loaded

Answer (score 0):

Once you change the structure of your DAG/tasks you need to restart the webserver (and probablly the scheduler too) in order to see the new changes on the gui. 
However if can also use the [cmd line interface](https://pythonhosted.org/airflow/cli.html) interface `>airflow list_tasks <dag_id>` among many other useful commands to test and run the new changes.

Comment: That's sounds suboptimal if I have to restart the webserver/acheduler everytime a new dag is submitted.