# How to automatically refresh DAGs through docker image in helm chart deployed Airflow

Tags: airflow, kubernetes-helm

I have a deployment of Airflow running in a kubernetes cluster. I deployed it there using the official helm chart ([described here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/installation/index.html#using-official-airflow-helm-chart)). I manage DAGs using the recommended way, by "baking" them into a docker image ([described here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/helm-chart/stable/manage-dags-files.html#bake-dags-in-docker-image)).

When I create or change a DAG, I run the `docker build` and `docker push` commands as listed in the documentation. This all works great. However, my changes don't show up in the GUI until I delete the scheduler and the webserver pods (`kubectl delete pod airflow-scheduler-xxx`, etc), forcing kubernetes to spin up new ones. This is not ideal for CI/CD purposes, as I don't want to continuously have to do this manually. Is there a way to pick up the changes automatically (e.g. by pulling the image periodically)?

I already tried to set `dag_dir_list_interval` in `airflow.cfg` ([suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43606311/refreshing-dags-without-web-server-restart-apache-airflow)) through the helm values, but this doesn't seem to change anything. `PullPolicy` is set to `Always` because I use the `latest` tag. It looks like this in my `override.yaml`:

```
images:
  airflow:
    repository: -registry-name-
    tag: latest
    pullPolicy: Always

config: 
  scheduler: 
    # after how much time a new DAGs should be picked up from the filesystem
    min_file_process_interval: 0
    dag_dir_list_interval: 60
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was eventually able to figure this out myself. The reason the pods weren't updating (i.e. weren't pulling the new image with the updated DAGs) is because I was using the `latest` tag. After building and pushing the new image, the cluster didn't know to pull that new image, because the tag was still the same. The solution is to not use the `latest` tag, but to use a tag that changes every time CI/CD runs. I chose to use `$(Build.SourceVersion)` in Azure Pipelines, which corresponds to the git hash of the commit that caused the pipeline to run. Then I added a `helm upgrade` command with a flag pointing to the new image tag. This command causes the relevant pods to be updated automatically.

```
helm upgrade --install airflow apache-airflow/airflow --set images.airflow.tag="$(Build.SourceVersion)"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you regularly change your DAG then you should consider gitSync.
whats is happening here is

1. Your airflow is deployed using your image lets say custom-airflow:1.0.0
   which means the scheduler webserver workers were deployed using the image 1.0.0
2. Now that you have changed your image lets say to 1.0.1, you have to redeploy airflow and its components in order to use the new image. Therefore if you dont redeploy airflow it would still be using the old image underneath the hood.

Ideally if you will use gitsync, the changes will reflect after approx 2 mins automatically.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. The reason I didn't choose the gitsync approach is because I don't want my cluster to have to pull changes from git every 2 minutes. This is also not the recommended approach, as per the official documentation. Since using a docker image is the recommended approach, I expected it to integrate well with CI/CD, without the need for manual refreshing of pods. This is indeed the case, as I described in my own answer.

Comment: Also the GitSync will only pick up dag changes. It won't pick up changes to plugins