# DAGS are not visible on the ui but it is present in the dags folder and in the ui under dag runs

Tags: airflow

Dags keeps disappearing from the ui of apache airflow

I am new to apache airflow , currently apache airflow version 2.7.1 is running on GKE which was deployed using helm, I created an example dag and pasted it in the dags folder and the code has no import or syntax error, after placing it in the dags directory I ran the command "airflow db init" and after that I was able to see the dag in the ui but after sometime it disappeared from the ui , after that I tried running "airflow dags reserialize" but again it was just present on the ui for some time and then again it disappeared, there is no dynamic dag also , really appreciate the help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Refreshing dags without web server restart apache airflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43606311/refreshing-dags-without-web-server-restart-apache-airflow)